# Angular 6 | Webpack Production Build Error

Tags: angular, webpack, rxjs, angular6, tsconfig

quick breakdown:

• Upgraded my Angular 5 application to Angular 6.
• Installed rxjs 6 & rxjs-compat 6
• Build using Webpack.
• Dev build works fine.
• Production build yields the following error:

> ERROR in chunk app [entry] bundle.js
>   /Users/Usr_Mac/Desktop/Angular/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js
>   RuntimeTemplate.moduleId(): Module
>   /Users/Usr_Mac/Desktop/Angular/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.jshas no id. This should not happen.

Comment: I've got the exact same error. JIT Build works without issues, but AOT yields this error

Answer (score 1):

This was a webpack bug - I had this issue at webpack 4.10.1.  Upgrading to 4.10.2 fixed it.

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7443

Answer (score 0):

Seems like rxjs bug. Try making a prod build without AoT and see if it helps:

```
ng build --prod --aot false
```

In general, I don't use rxjs-compat. Making a clean upgrade from Angular 5 to Angular 6 doesn't take much time. I blogged about it here:
https://yakovfain.com/2018/05/16/how-i-migrated-a-dozen-of-projects-to-angular-6/

Comment: Thank you for sharing you blog. I cannot run ng commands in my project because I did not use the angular CLI to create this application. Thus, to build the application, I have the following files which need to be configured:
• tscongif.json •tscongif.aot.json •webpack.config.common.js •webpack.congif.dev.js •webpack.congif.prod.js

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it is only working (in my case) if I changed one line of code in the rxjs module (file `node_modules/rxjs/package.json`).

Changed

```
"sideEffects": false,
```

to

```
"sideEffects": true,
```

With this change in place also the AOT build is working. I don't know why this change is necessary, because the module loading of rxjs should be without side effects, at least the sideEffects/webpack github issues are closed and I don't found any (open) issues regarding this setting.

Maybe this is a issue when combining angular+AOT+webpack+rxjs?!

**Workaround/Solution**

As a workaround - as long there is no better solution to this issue - you can add something like this in your package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "sed -i -e 's/\"sideEffects\": false,/\"sideEffects\": true,/g' node_modules/rxjs/package.json"
},
```

This will replace the problematic sideEffects config of the rxjs module.